# Comparing two columns in a csv file using python based on value in third column

Tags: python, csv

I have three columns in a csv file

```
Number    Value      Checked
1111        5           
1234        6          
1111        0          yes
4444        0          yes
5555        8
4444        7
```

If the checked field is "yes" I need to find the if the Number associated with it is repeated in the Number column. If it is then I want Checked field to show "yes"

Example output:

```
Number    Value      Checked
1111        5          yes
1234        6          
1111        0          yes
4444        0          yes
5555        8
4444        7          yes
```

I'm using python. This is a csv file.
I'm sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Basically I’m trying to read the rows in a column that have values that total to 0. If they are 0, then I have created a column “Checked” that says “yes” to values that become null. For Example if the Number “111111” has Values “-8” and “8”, then after performing sumif,  it would say 0 and hence, checked field would be “yes”. But the problem is my code reads one row after the other, therefore if there are two rows with values “9” and “-9”, I get 0 for only the second row and not the first row. I want the checked column to add “yes” for both the rows.
Here’s a section of my code:

```
    edict={}
    if edict.get(newrow[-10],"")=="":  
       edict[newrow[-10]]=newrow[47]
    else:  
       edict[newrow[-10]]=float(newrow[47])+float(edict[newrow[-10]])                            
    newrow[-9]=edict[newrow[-10]]
    if newrow[-9]==0:
       newrow[-11]="Hide"
```

row-10 is the field Number
row47 is Value
row-11 is Checked

Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: please format your strings

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far...

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! A few questions: What are you showing us here? It's not a CSV file - I don't see any commas. What part of the problem are you having problems with? Please show your code so we can find out how it might be improved or corrected. I suppose you're not expecting us to just write that program for you, so you might want to give us more information than what you have provided here. There are some good pointers here: [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: Comments are quite unsuitable for posting code, but you can always [edit your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29265735/edit). Also, please make sure you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Algo:

1. Read input CSV file by `csv` module.
2. Create two variables, `info` to save rows details and `checked_value` for checked yes numbers.
3. Iterate every row from the input file.
4. Add row into `info`
5. Check if row is checked to `yes` or not, If yes append `row[0]` number in the `checked_value` list.
6. Iterate `info` dictionary and check every row again if `row[0]` number in `checked_value` list or not, If present the update row to `yes`.
7. Write New CSV file.

--

code:

```
import csv
import pprint

input_file = "input1.csv"

with open(input_file, 'rb') as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp)
    info = {}
    checked_value = []
    for i, row in enumerate(root):
        info[i]  = row
        if row[2]=="yes":
            checked_value.append(row[0])

print "Debug 1: info: "
pprint.pprint(info)

for i,j in info.items():
    if j[0] in checked_value:
        j[2] = "yes"

print "Debug 2: info: "
pprint.pprint(info)


#- Write file
with open("output1.csv", 'wb') as fp:
    root = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    root.writerows(info.values())
```

Output:
Debug statements:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/anna$ python 6.py 
Debug 1: info: 
{0: ['Number', 'Value', 'Checked'],
 1: ['1111', '5', ''],
 2: ['1234', '6', ''],
 3: ['1111', '0', 'yes'],
 4: ['4444', '0', 'yes'],
 5: ['5555', '8', ''],
 6: ['4444', '7', '']}
Debug 2: info: 
{0: ['Number', 'Value', 'Checked'],
 1: ['1111', '5', 'yes'],
 2: ['1234', '6', ''],
 3: ['1111', '0', 'yes'],
 4: ['4444', '0', 'yes'],
 5: ['5555', '8', ''],
 6: ['4444', '7', 'yes']}
```

Output1.csv

```
Number,Value,Checked
1111,5,yes
1234,6,
1111,0,yes
4444,0,yes
5555,8,
4444,7,yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, when I added the code, I get the following error  File "test.py", line 343, in exp1
    if j[-10] in checked_value:
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @python_rookie1: Can you pass me your input cvs file and py code on my email vivekbsable@gmail.com ?

Comment: @python_rookie1: Welcome. Is my answer useful for you? If yes then upvote/ accept :P

Comment: It was very useful, however I cannot upvote for Im new (need 15 points)! :(